# Maven find dependey but not the class

Tags: maven, module, dependencies

I have a Maven module project with 4 modules and a remote parent. I'm trying to compile the modules separately, in the correct order, but I am having a compilation error: cannot find symbol

The structure is something like this:

4 modules:

- Modul A
- Modul B
- Modul C
- Modul D

And de depency relation is:

- Modul B depends on A
- Modul C depends on B
- Modul D depends on C

The **module B** it's finding the dependency because if I change the name of the dependency of **module A**, other error is thrown. I recompiled the **module A** lot of times.

I think the trouble is not related to parent, because I am compiling the modules separately.

If need code snnipet just ask for it

Comment: You should build from the parent and not each module separately.

Comment: But how Can I build from the parent if it is a remote parent located in a remote repository? If I am not wrong, maven finds first of all on local repository, right?